# Session.get module from sqlAlchemy not working in Kivy mobile app built with Buildozer. How to fix?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, kivy, buildozer

I have been working on a mobile app in Python that interacts with a locally hosted MySQL database.

The app works perfectly fine on desktop. However upon transforming it into a .apk using buildozer, I am no longer able to use the Session.get() module from sqlAlchemy, as it raises the error "AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'get'".

I have been able to successfully upload and download information from the server, so I am quite confident that it is not a server issue. Furthermore, the exact same operation does work on desktop, so it doesn't appear like a faulty request either.

Some snippets of the code are as follows:

```py
engine = db.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://name:password@databaseip")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

conn = engine.connect()
metadata = db.MetaData()
db.MetaData.reflect(metadata, bind=engine)
    
Base = declarative_base()
```

Then all the Tables are defined in python, and an example of a failing function is as follows:

```py
def archive_task(task_id: int):     
    selected_task = session.get(Task, task_id)     
    selected_task.archived = 1     
    session.commit()
```

I am running this on sqlalchemy version 2.0.12. I used buildozer to create an APK file for android.
sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy.orm are included in this list of requirements for the buildozer.spec.

On desktop, this does successfully change the archive parameter of the task.

Oddly enough, other functions do work flawlessly, such as the following:

```py
def upload_task(description, long_info, option, department_id, model): 
   session.add(Task(description=description, information=long_info, department_id=department_id, 
   option=option, stage=0, model=model, archived=0))     
   session.commit()
```

Any tips would be appreciated.